# how to add css to change liferay basic view?

Tags: liferay, portlet, liferay-6

I want to use some custom ui in my liferay site .How can i make it possible

Like if i want to change this portion of liferay?

[image]

I have made one css file for this but its just overlay this followingsection.

so any way to edit this section of liferay with css?

Answer (score 3):

The right way to do this is to create a theme which will have a template directory setup that will merge specific css to the ones which the system is based on.

http://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.0/development/-/ai/creating-a-theme

Alternatively for a quick hack without going through the full theme development process you can change the css in the folder:

liferay-portal-6.1.10-ee-ga1\tomcat-7.0.25\webapps\ROOT\html\themes\classic\css

provided that you are using the default classic theme.

This is of course not the recommended way but will work.

Answer (score 0):

The Screen shot you have put in the post will be visible only for Admin user. Only you as admin can see that kind of controls on the page. End Users who are under your defined role and who dont have access to edit something will not see that portion of the page. That said, you dont have to bother about changing the colour of the portion of the page that you put in the SS. You will have to bother about the portion of the page below that. That can be done only by Custom Theme development. Once you create your custom theme, you will need to make CSS changes in `custom.css`. Even if you want to change the colour of the default theme provided by Liferay, you will have to edit in custom.css file. This is because custom.css file gets loaded at the end and it will override other css files acting upon.