# how to change css to change liferay basic view

Tags: javascript, css, liferay, portal

I want to change some css like i want to hide **Powered By Life ray** in life ray portal 6.2-ce-ga2. And want to make some changes that i want to make iframes resposive in portal web page. I have short time so i am unable to develop custom theme. i have to meke another css with small change that i have to be imported or can i change existing css. I want to hide following text. Is this can be possible with JavaScript then how can i add this because i also tried to add JavaScript but it also did not worked for me. i have tried to get element by alert(document.getElementsByClassName('powered-by').innerHTML+"ss"); but not worked.

[image]

Comment: where is your sample code? without sample no one will answer your question.

Comment: i tried to change existing css but no effect on portal?? what i have to do to change css. i  tried only to change css only. can u tell me how??

Comment: i also try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12932183/how-to-add-css-to-change-liferay-basic-view

Comment: if your css not worked there can be JS effecting and conflicting your css code.

Comment: i  have not applied any JS .. built in javaScript can creat problem??

Comment: maybe.  if you want to change css of the default theme provided by Liferay, you will have to edit in custom.css file

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99169/discussion-between-lemon-kazi-and-nagi).

Answer (score 0):

For that modify portal_normal.vm you have to create new theme and relate it to
parent theme.